# WPF units on window and canvas are different. What is window size unit?

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I create a WPF project and run the code below I get the window below. I am confused, as both ellips diameter and window width/height are "200", but ellipse does not fit in window.

Also, I am not posting an image, but I tried to set the height and width of the window to 96 in a previous experiment, and the height was less than width. The aspect ratio kinda looked like the aspect ratio of my display.

I read that in WPF each unit is 1/96 inches. I assume this is true for ellipse in the canvas. Then, what about the window size? What unit does it use?

image:

[Simple WPF application window image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAspy.png)

code:

```
<Window x:Class="clock2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:clock2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas ClipToBounds="True">
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="0.0" Canvas.Top="0.0" Width="200.0" Height="200.0" Fill="lightgray" />

        </Canvas>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Width and Height of the Window includes the dimensions of the border and title bar.

Set the size of the Grid instead, and set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` on the Window:

```
<Window ... SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid Height="200" Width="200">
        <Canvas ClipToBounds="True">
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="0.0" Canvas.Top="0.0"
                     Width="200.0" Height="200.0" Fill="LightGray" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the size of the canvas and use the `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` you can get rid of the grid:

```
<Window ... SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Canvas Width="200" Height="200" Background="Aqua">
        <Ellipse Width="200" Height="200" Fill="red" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```